# Use ggplot to plot numbers (price index) against factors (quarterly dates) for a single variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very simple question:

My data is as follows:

`dateq     equal.weighted
2000q1     100
2000q2     103
2000q3     105
2000q4     108`

I used the following code to plot this data, but the graph shows no line inside, could you please help me, many thanks!

```
ggplot(GlobalPriceData, aes(dateq, equally.weighted)) + geom_line() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line plot with factor variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011518/line-plot-with-factor-variables-in-r)

Comment: Use `group = 1` within `aes` as suggested in the linked duplicate post, also your column is called `equal.weighted` not `equally.weighted`

Answer (score 0):

You should trasform your date column in an appropriate date format:

```
library(zoo) # for as.yearqtr() and scale_x_yearqtr()
d$dateq <- as.yearqtr(d$dateq)

ggplot(d, aes(x = dateq, y = equal.weighted)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_yearqtr(limits = c(min(d$dateq), max(d$dateq)),
                  format = "%YQ%q") # this sets the proper scale format for the ax
```

[image]

Data:

```
tt <- "dateq     equal.weighted
2000q1     100
2000q2     103
2000q3     105
2000q4     108"

d <- read.table(text=tt, header = T)
```